# from null to 0 in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala I need to evaluate a expression like this:

```
  Some(((for { **** SOME CONDITION ****} yield ps.price.get * ps.quantity.get ).sum).toString)
```

The problem I get is that the values for price or quantity can be null (not existent in the database) and therefore I get the error:

```
  [NoSuchElementException: None.get]
```

If price is null then I need a way to obtain 0 from  ps.price.get and the same for ps.quantity.get so I can use  sum. Price and quantity are

```
                        Option[scala.math.BigDecimal]
```

How can I do this?

Note: I tried

```
   yield ps.price.getOrElse(0) * ps.quantity.getOrElse(0)
```

but in this case I get the error:

```
     value * is not a member of Any
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your orElse case needs to be the correct type for both prices and quantity:

```
yield ps.price.getOrElse(0d) * ps.quantity.getOrElse(BigDecimal(0))
```

Comment: I am getting "   value * is not a member of Any  " error

Comment: what type is quantity? if long, use `0L`

Comment: Option[scala.math.BigDecimal]

Comment: The point is you orElse case needs to be the correct type, so make it the Zero value for BigDecimal and the code will be ok.

Comment: I used:  

         yield (ps.price.getOrElse(BigDecimal(0))).toFloat * (ps.quantity.getOrElse(BigDecimal(0))).toFloat).sum)

and all worked!!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use something like this (for comprehension):

```
for {
  // some conditions
} yield {
  // now ps.price and ps.quantity are options
  (ps.price, ps.quantity) match {
    case (Some(p), Some(q)) => p * q
    case _ => new BigDecimal(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good but it did not run for me because of the  new  word. It worked if using just  BigDecimal(0)  instead of  new BigDecimal(0).  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
val prices = for {
  ps <- listOfPs
  price <- ps.price
  quantity <- ps.quantity
  if // put condition here
} yield price * quantity

prices.sum.toString
```